# Editar XML através do Nodo de uma TreeView WPF - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, eventos-do-mouse, treeview

Estou com uma dúvida, eu tenho um código que cria uma TreeView dinamicamente através de um código c#. A `TreeView` foi criada no WPF.

Meu objetivo é criar uma função que abra um item `XML` e criei uma `TreeView`, e em seguida seja possível alterar um nodo dessa `TreeView` e ele ser editado diretamente no `XML`.

Então, a primeira parte eu concluí com êxito, que é a abertura do `XML` em uma `TreeView`.

Segue o código:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : DXRibbonWindow
{

    //fazer diagrama depois.

    private TreeViewItem tree = new TreeViewItem();
    private OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    private XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AbrirDispositivoClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Deixando a tree view habilitada.
        tvDispositivo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        //Abrir arquivos com extensão .xml
        dlg.CheckFileExists = true;
        dlg.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
        dlg.Multiselect = false;


        if (dlg.ShowDialog() != true) { return; }
        try
        {
            XMLdoc.Load(dlg.FileName);
        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O arquivo XML é invalido!");
            return;
        }

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(dlg.FileName, settings);
        tree = new TreeViewItem();
        tree.Header = "Dipositivo";
        tvDispositivo.Items.Add(tree);
        BuildArvore(reader, tree);
    }

    private void BuildArvore(XmlReader reader, TreeViewItem TreeViewItem)
    {
        TreeViewItem NovoNodo = new TreeViewItem();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    NovoNodo.Header = reader.Value;
                    TreeViewItem.Items.Add(NovoNodo);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    TreeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)TreeViewItem.Parent;
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (!reader.IsEmptyElement)
                    {
                        NovoNodo.Header = reader.Name;
                        TreeViewItem.Items.Add(NovoNodo);
                        TreeViewItem = NovoNodo;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NovoNodo.Header = reader.NodeType.ToString();
                        TreeViewItem.Items.Add(NovoNodo);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    NovoNodo.Header = reader.NodeType.ToString();
                    TreeViewItem.Items.Add(NovoNodo);
                    break;
            }
            NovoNodo = new TreeViewItem();
        }
    }

    private void EditarNodo(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        if (tvDispositivo.SelectedItem is TreeViewItem)
        {   
            TreeViewItem item = tvDispositivo.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
            string texto = item.Header.ToString();
            item.Header = new TextBox()
            {
                Text = texto
            };
        }

    }
```

O evento `EditarNodo`, é para que com um duplo clique eu habilite uma `TextBox` no local do nodo selecionado.

O que me falta agora é a possibilidade de editar este nodo e concluir apertando enter. Eu procurei alguns exemplos mas não achei em nenhum lugar. Alguém aí sabe como posso fazer isso no código .cs e não no XAML?

Segue abaixo o XAML:

```
 <TreeView x:Name="tvDispositivo" Visibility="Hidden" MouseDoubleClick="EditarNodo"  />
```